# mean time of two string time in java

Tags: java

I have two times variable as string 
want to find the mean time. please help me

```
inTime = shift.getInTime()+":00";
outTime = shift.getOutTime()+":00";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date d1=df.parse(inTime);
Date d2 = df.parse(outTime);
long date1InMilSec=d1.getTime();
long date2InMilSec=d2.getTime();
long half =date1InMilSec + ((date2InMilSec - date1InMilSec) / 2);
long minute = (half / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hour = (half / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
```

Comment: And what doesn't work with that code?

Comment: inTime =09:30:00  outTime = 15:30:00  i get time = 07:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if I use your code and set fixed time values, then I get `11:30:00` instead of your `07:00:00`, so there is maybe something else wrong with `inTime` and `outTime`.

Since I get `11:30:00` there is maybe something wrong with your calculation of hour and minute, but I won't bother that. Let's use a new `Date` instance to do the conversion:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date d1 = df.parse("09:30:00");
Date d2 = df.parse("15:30:00");
long date1InMilSec = d1.getTime();
long date2InMilSec = d2.getTime();
long half = date1InMilSec + ((date2InMilSec - date1InMilSec) / 2);
Date meanTime = new Date(half); // new Date instance, instead of own calculation
String time = df.format(meanTime);
System.out.println(time);
```

This code prints:

```
12:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String inTime = "09:30:00";
String outTime = "15:30:00";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date dateIn  = df.parse(inTime);
Date dateOut = df.parse(outTime);
long dateInMill  = dateIn.getTime();
long dateOutMill = dateOut.getTime();
long dateMiddleMill = dateInMill + ((dateOutMill - dateInMill) / 2);

Date dateMiddle = new Date(dateMiddleMill);
System.out.println(df.format(dateMiddle));
```